# User permission in sharepoint and .Net

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, asp.net

I am creating a project to upload documents to SharePoint from asp.net .I want to achieve a condition where if the user is present in Sharepoint 2010 he should be able to upload the document otherwise the user should not be able to upload.

how to achieve this?